# Border values at which timeseries decrease and increase

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, moving-average, pandas

I have a timeseries data of signals in stock market (`[-1, 1]`) and I want to find mean values at which I have down trend and upwards trend.
I already used Moving Average and Autocorrelation, but it’s not exactly what I need.

For example, here's ts data

[image]

And I want to find two values, like `signal < 0.1` and `signal > 0.05` correspond to values decreasing and increasing.

Comment: It would be helfpuf if you illustrate your point by an example.

Comment: @utobi, made an edit

Comment: @Michael The example for the stock data has negative values, Stock value cannot be negative, Is this a differenced/Return dataset?

Comment: @Justice_Lords, my bad, it's signal data from stock trading dataset. It can be in `[-1, 1]` range